# How to get Inactive Months cumulatively using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, data-analysis

I have a sales table as following

| Customer | Sale_order_ID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1211 | 21/06/2022 | 1000 |
| A | 1212 | 05/07/2022 | 1250 |
| B | 1213 | 25/07/2022 | 1500 |
| A | 1214 | 25/07/2022 | 1550 |
| B | 1215 | 11/09/2022 | 1000 |
| B | 1216 | 05/10/2022 | 1250 |
| A | 1217 | 25/10/2022 | 1500 |
| B | 1218 | 28/10/2022 | 1550 |

I'm trying to get the inactive months (no sale order wrt month).

I do also have a table which has start dates of every month and year

I require the output as mentioned below:

| Customer | Start_Date_of_Month | Sales_order_count | Inactive_Months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/06/2022 | 1 | null |
| A | 01/07/2022 | 2 | null |
| A | 01/08/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 01/09/2022 | 0 | 2 |
| A | 01/10/2022 | 1 | null |
| B | 01/07/2022 | 1 | null |
| B | 01/08/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 01/09/2022 | 1 | null |
| B | 01/10/2022 | 2 | null |

For Customer A the 1st sale order date is on 21/06/2022 and For customer B the 1st sale order date is on 25/07/2022. So the output should be based on their first sale order date

Comment: You have omitted to show your expected output

Comment: sorry, made changes

Comment: can you provide also the existing SQL you created, the one with "Sales_order_count"?

Comment: I've not yet created. But it would be 
Select
Customer,
date_trunc(month, Date) as Start_Date_of_Month,
count(Sale_order_ID) as Sales_order_count
from Sales
group by Customer,
date_trunc(month, Date)

Comment: Generate calendar table (recursive CTE), leftjoin your data to it and define the rows presence, obtain needed data.

Comment: *it would be Select Customer, date_trunc(month, Date) as Start_Date_of_Month, ..* The function DATE_TRUNC not exists in MySQL. Check your DBMS.